# Stackful coroutines + gdb = "previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack)?"

Tags: c++, gdb, coroutine, dwarf, fibers

I'm writing some code to debug stackful coroutines that use Boost.Context's `make_fcontext` and `jump_fcontext`, and have run into a small problem.

Normally it is not possible to `backtrace` past the entry of a stackful coroutine as it executes on its own stack. This means that I cannot determine from a debugger from where a coroutine was entered. This, however, is not the problem about which I am asking. I already solved this problem by adding some inline assembly and DWARF bytecode in the function I pass to `make_fcontext`:

```
__asm__ volatile (
  "mov %[caller_fcontext_t] %[somewhere]\n\t"
  ".cfi_escape /* DWARF bytecode to load caller_fcontext_t from "
  "             * somewhere and use it to load all the registers saved "
  "             * there by jump_fcontest */"
  "call %[another_function]"
  : /* stuff */ : /* stuff */ : /* stuff */)
```

This really does work and I can now `backtrace` to the point in the caller where it starts or resumes the inner coroutine - but only sometimes.

It turns out that gdb has a "sanity check": if the stack pointer moves in the "wrong" direction between call frames, gdb assumes that the stack is corrupt and stops the trace with the message "`Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)`".

This gets triggered when my stacks are allocated in certain ways, but not in other ways. I even have a test with statically allocated stacks that triggers this failure when used in forward order but not when used in reverse order.

I even found the portion of gdb's source code that performs this check here: https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/gdb/frame.c#L737-L816

Now here's my actual question: **How can I fix this?**

Is there some assembly incantation I can write that tells GDB "trust me, I know what I'm doing"?

Comment: Do you have any reference code or any specific documentation, I am trying to implement the same kind of logic in my fibers implementation but I haven't been able to find a solution yet :(

Comment: GDB ignores this heuristic for inline functions. So my solution was to wrap the `jump_fcontext` call in two functions: one `__attribute__((noinline))` and the other `__attribute__((force_inline))`. I used trial and error to find the combination that worked at all optimization levels used by my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now here's my actual question: How can I fix this?
>
> Is there some assembly incantation I can write that tells GDB "trust
>   me, I know what I'm doing"?

There currently is no way to do this.  It would be a good idea, but probably would require a DWARF extension of some kind.  So, it may be difficult to implement.

You can see the evidence of this in the gdb sources: GCC had a similar issue involving `-fsplit-stack`, and this was worked around by simply coding the name of the offending function into gdb:

```
  if (!morestack_name || strcmp (morestack_name, "__morestack") != 0)
```

A quick workaround for your personal use is to just comment out the [early return here](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/gdb/frame.c#L2034-L2035).

Comment: Excellent answer. I noticed that for some optimization levels, I do not encounter this failure in either direction. Specifically `-O0 -g` and `-O3` fail with "previous frame inner to this frame", but `-O2 -g` and `-O3 -g` don't. I suspect it has to do with how functions are inlined. Is there some combination of always inline and never inline I can use to trick gdb for any combination of compile flags?

Comment: Not that I know of, actually I'm surprised to hear that it could be circumvented this way.  I don't have a theory for why that would be the case.